# How copy Assets folder to internal storage?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have copy many posible solutions from here and any unsuccess from me. I'm try to copy asset folder to storage data but always get error in logs after try to copy assets data

```java
private void copyAssets() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String[] files = null;
        try {
            files = assetManager.list("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
        }
        for(String filename : files) {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+filename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                in = assetManager.open(filename);
                //File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/"+getApplicationInfo().packageName+"/", filename);
                File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/osmdroid/", filename);
                out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                //out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
            }
        }
    }
    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

Pleasy, Any know about this error??

```
06-23 18:06:06.316 10803-10803/com.restaurantesencuba.myapplication E/tag: Failed to copy asset file: images
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: images
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error, actually while debugging I found "images", "sounds" and "webkit", so seems to be you should just skip the non existing ones, because there is no other way to check if they exist:

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
String[] files;
try {
    files = assetManager.list("");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
    return;
}
for(String filePath : files) {
    try {
        InputStream in = assetManager.open(filePath);
        //do your work...
    } catch (IOException ignored) { }
}
```